# Java: How does compression works over http

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I was trying to set compression in tomcat container by setting compression on in server.xml, here is the snippet:

```
           <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443"
           compression="on"
           compressionMinSize="10"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,application/json" />
```

On my client program I used the following code to get some data from server, the data that I get is of 200 bytes.

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(_strServiceURL + "/addnumber");
    post.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(strAddNumber);
    entity.setContentType("application/xml");
    post.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

when i got response from server I am not able to determine whether the tomcat is compressing the response or not, how can I know at the client side.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There should be a header in the response that says so.

Comment: You can use a packet sniffer or similar tool to see what's going over the wire. Compressed data will look like random garbage, instead of the data you're trying to send over (e.g. json text).

Comment: Why do you need to determine that? The client must automatically handle this if he advertises this capability.